# Not Understanding Essence of "Longest Substring with At Least K Repeating Characters"

Tags: python, string, algorithm

This is a question regarding question #395 on LeetCode, entitled ["Longest Substring with At Least K Repeating Characters."](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-with-at-least-k-repeating-characters)

Someone posted a remarkably concise solution (in Python), and I am having trouble understanding the idea at the core of this approach. I can follow the code (reproduced below) mechanically, but I can't quite grasp the core idea here. For instance, I see that it counts the characters in the string and recursively splits the string at characters for which the count is less than the prescribed maximum number of characters (k).

```
def longestSubstring(self, s, k):
    for c in set(s):
        if s.count(c) < k:
            return max(self.longestSubstring(t, k) for t in s.split(c))
    return len(s)
```

The author says (emphasis added), "If every character appears at least k times, the whole string is ok. Otherwise split by a least frequent character (**because it will always be too infrequent and thus can’t be part of any ok substring**) and make the most out of the splits."

Why is it that when a character is too infrequent, it necessarily cannot be part of any valid substring?

Comment: Not really an SO question.

Comment: @SuperStew Why not?  It's not opinion-based, it's very specific, working code is provided.

Comment: Most SO questions deal with specific code problems, rather than explanations or analysis of what sounds like a working solution.

Comment: You shouldn't have blindly copied the title of the LC problem. The description is much clearer, it talks about finding a substring "such that every character in [substring] appears no less than k times". Occurring less than k times in a string implies it occurs less than k times in every possible substring thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question:

> Find the length of the longest substring T of a given string (consists of lowercase letters only) such that **every** character in T appears no less than k times.

The question states that every character in the string needs to appear at least k times, therefore every character that is too infrequent cannot be a part of any substring.

Comment: Chalk this up to my misinterpreting the written directions. Sometimes you just need someone to point out how dumb you are. Thanks for the help.